# How django works with foreign key?

Tags: sql, django

I development system in Django and I really i love it. However I want improve my code but I have doubts how Django works with **Foreign Keys**.

Example:

```
class A(model.Models):
   b = model.IntegerField()

class C(model.Models):
   d = models.ForeignKey(A)


#getting...
value = C.objects.get(id=1)

print value.d.b
```

When i access property **b** from class A. Do django realize consult in DB? or realize consult in command **C.objects.get(id=1)**?

If django consult when i try to access property .Will  he always consult in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
value = C.objects.select_related('d').get(pk=1)
```

This should prevent it from making another trip to the database.

See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related.

Comment: O.o I need pay attetion more. In project i work with many foreign.

Answer (score 1):

you can check [Caching and QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) to understand  who  will be checked db or cache